# RecyclerView in Fragment doesn't show items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

In `onViewCreated`, `setMonthView()` init recyclerView and `nextBtn, prevBtn` perform same function, `setMonthView()`.
When I click Button, the recyclerView shows items but when the fragment created first time, recyclerView doesn't show anything. What's wrong with my code?

I set recyclerView height to wrap-content and each time the button clicked, layout changes like below.

**when I just run the app:**[image: when I just run the app]

**when I click next/prev Button**[image]

**click more(Month Text is getting weird)**[image]

**click a lot, the month text gone**[image]

```
class CalendarPage : Fragment(), CalendarAdapter.OnItemListener{
    lateinit var manager: InputManager
    private lateinit var nextMonthBtn : ImageButton
    private lateinit var prevMonthBtn : ImageButton
    private lateinit var monthYearText: TextView
    private lateinit var calendarRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var selectDate: LocalDate
    private lateinit var selectedDayTextView:TextView
    private lateinit var calendarAdapter: CalendarAdapter
    private lateinit var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        selectDate = LocalDate.now()
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        if(arguments!=null) manager = requireArguments().getSerializable("manager") as InputManager
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_calendar_page, container, false)

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initWidgets()
        setMonthView()
        initBtn(view)
    }


    fun initBtn(v: View){
        nextMonthBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.nextMonth)
        nextMonthBtn.setOnClickListener{
            nextMonthAction()
        }
        prevMonthBtn = v.findViewById(R.id.prevMonth)
        prevMonthBtn.setOnClickListener{
            previousMonthAction()
        }
    }

    private fun previousMonthAction() {
        selectDate = selectDate.minusMonths(1)
        setMonthView()
    }

    private fun nextMonthAction() {
        selectDate = selectDate.plusMonths(1)
        setMonthView()
    }



    fun initWidgets() {
        calendarRecyclerView = requireView().findViewById(R.id.calendarRecyclerView)
        monthYearText = requireView().findViewById(R.id.monthYearIV)
    }


    fun setMonthView() {
        monthYearText.text = monthYearfromDate(selectDate)
        Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), monthYearfromDate(selectDate), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val daysInMonth = daysInMonthArray(selectDate)
        calendarAdapter = CalendarAdapter(daysInMonth, this)
        layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 7)
        calendarRecyclerView.adapter = calendarAdapter
        calendarRecyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

    }
```

Comment: Try to set layoutmanager before setting adapter to recyclerview

Comment: Debug `CalendarAdapter` see if it has Items or not also check RecyclerView Size in xml and the container you are using for fragment .. Whats the value of `daysInMonth` for first time ? Seems like some logical error so debug it .

Comment: I found that when I set recyclerView height to "wrap-content" and press the button, the layout is getting weird.